# Ammaps legend only appears on window resize, Not able to see when it rendered

Tags: javascript, angularjs, amcharts

I have create map using javascript Amcharts functions. this is my code -

```
var recentlyLegend = {"id":"recentlyLegendDiv","width":155,"maxColumns":1,"backgroundAlpha":0,"left":0,"top":350,"horizontalGap":10,"switchable":true,"switchType":"x","markerSize":16,"fontSize":10,"data": recentlyWorldLegendData};


$scope.regionByCountryGeoMap = function(chart){
                    var source = worldLevelProcessImages(chart.data, recentlyWorldDataProvider, recentlyLegendColorArray);
                    AmCharts.theme = AmCharts.themes.dark;
                    recentlyMap = new AmCharts.AmMap();
                    recentlyMap.mouseWheelZoomEnabled = true;
                    recentlyMap.zoomControl = {
                        panControlEnabled: false,
                        zoomControlEnabled: true,
                        top: 60,
                        left: 15,
                        gridHeight: 100,
                        iconSize:9,
                        gridBackgroundAlpha: 0
                    };
                    recentlyMap.responsive = {
                        enabled: true
                      };
                    recentlyMap.areasSettings = {color: "#D8DDDF", selectable: true, selectedColor: "#436BFF", outlineColor: "#fff", outlineThickness:
0.5};
                    recentlyMap.imagesSettings.balloonText = "<div align='left' style='font-size:10px;'>[[title]]</div>";
                    recentlyMap.imagesSettings.bringForwardOnHover = false;
                    recentlyMap.legend = recentlyLegend;
                    recentlyMap.hiddenLegendItems = {};
                    recentlyMap.addListener('init', function () {
                        recentlyMap.preventDragOut = true;
                        recentlyMap.legend.switchable = true;
                        recentlyMap.legend.addListener('clickMarker', recentlyHandleLegendClick);
                        recentlyMap.legend.addListener('clickLabel', recentlyHandleLegendClick);
                    });
                    recentlyMap.addListener("rendered", function () {
                        recentlyMap.initialZoomLatitude = recentlyMap.zoomLatitude();
                        recentlyMap.initialZoomLongitude = recentlyMap.zoomLongitude();
                    });
                    recentlyMap.dataProvider = source;
                    recentlyMap.addListener("clickMapObject", handleMapObjectClick);
                    recentlyMap.export = {
                    enabled: true,
                    position: "bottom-right"
                    };
                    recentlyMap.write(chart.chartId);
                }
```

Map has been rendered properly but legends only appears on window resize and its also not taking custom css for legends

Can anyone give solution for this?

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your issue in the form of a fiddle? I stubbed out what I could but your code works fine for me [here](http://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/4484f112cd3b921ddf3a1439bd25c81c?editors=0010).

Comment: My charts are not rendering on page reload. I am using clink event to rendered chart on the same page. That's may be a reason to facing this issue.

Comment: Also, legends div not taking custom CSS in my case.

Comment: It's hard to troubleshoot your case without seeing a demo that replicates your issue. Make a fiddle/plunker/codepen so we can see it and provide suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

After writing the chart to html, try to call validate data and validate size methods.

i.e After

```
recentlyMap.write(chart.chartId);
```

this line write the following

```
recentlyMap.validateData();

recentlyMap.validateSize();
```

I have used this methods over normal map.I'm not sure about map

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem in my own amMap, which was also failing to show the legend until the browser resized. The solution was setting additional values in the configuration for my responsive plugin (you're using this plugin too).

The issue relates to the sizing of the map - the responsive plugin will automatically attempt to hide components of the legend bit by bit as the map shrinks and eventually, the entire legend will get hidden as the size of the map becomes smaller than amMap's default responsive breakpoints.

In your configuration, instead of this:

```
"responsive": {
   "enabled": true
},
// ... rest of conf here ...
```

Try this:

```
"responsive": {
    "enabled": true,
    "rules": [
        {
            "minHeight": 0,
            "overrides": {
                "legend": {
                    "enabled": true
                }
            }
        }
    ]
},
// ... rest of conf here ...
```

This says: "if the map is taller than 0px tall (which it should always be if you're setting your own width and height styles), show the legend.".

I'm not sure what's going on under the hood in amMaps when you don't provide a `rules` array but it seems like it applies it's own rules for you if you don't provide them yourself.

Here's a good knowledgebase article explaining the responsive plugin:
https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/making-charts-responsive/